# How can I determine which role I've received after logging into AWS Cognito via JavaScript?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

After I log in to AWS Cognito via my browser, I get an access key and a secret access key along w/a session token, but I can't see which role I've been assigned. I know which role I should be assigned, but is there a way to programmatically validate this?

I'm trying to use the role I've been assigned to access a restricted bucket, but am so far not having any success and one of the ways for me to trouble shoot this is to determine which role I've been assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [sts.GetCallerIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/STS.html#getCallerIdentity-property).

cli example (js link above):

```
aws --profile XXXXXXXX sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "AIDAIXXXXXXXXTHOVLM",
    "Account": "123456789098",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789098:user/dan"
}
```

It is indeed frustrating to debug without this, and it didn't used to exist, but now it does.  Hurrah!